# How to give permissions to Dropbox, but remove all rights of other users on Windows

Tags: windows-8, file-permissions, dropbox

I have Windows 8.1, Dropbox client is installed and is using folder X to sync data. How can i forbid access to X to all Windows accounts except mine and that this does not affect Dropbox client permissions. When I removed "Users" and "Authenticated users" from X security permissions Dropbox client  was unable to access X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your dropbox folder on your harddrive. Rightclick the folder and select properties.

```
1. Go to the security tab.
2. Click Advanced
3. Click the tab Owner
4. Click Edit
5. Click on your username in the `Change owner to` field.
6. Hit apply, and apply to all files/folders and subfolders.
```

Go back to the security tab and do the following `before` hitting `apply`:

```
1. Press Edit...
2. Remove everything but SYSTEM
3. Add your own user and give it Full control
4. Hit apply
```

Make sure that Dropbox can still synchronise. If not, restart dropbox and try again.

Comment: Works now, do you know why it didn't work when it was SYSTEM + Administrators. I assumed that this will do the trick as I am in administrators, and other users were not.

Comment: This can have several reasons. For example, if your computer is in a domain, it will use the domain's administrators group before using the local administrators group. Additionally, setting the owner makes sure only you have access, no one else.

Comment: Wow, domain is right answer, did't think of that. I was already the owner, so this was not the reason. Thank you LPChip for fast and correct answers and diagnostic!

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to use pcname\administrators as a group and it will work for all local administrators.